# How to add text under the barcode: php-barcode-generator

Tags: php, composer-php

First of all I want to give you my congratulations for such an excellent liberia created for the generation of barcodes.

my question is how can I add the barcode characters below it?

pass from a barcode without characters:
[image]

to this barcode with characters:
[image]

I use one library for composer name is php-barcode-generator and this is my code:

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code - not a screenshot so users can help you properly.

Comment: Per [the library's docs](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator), "We also only generate the 'bars' part of a barcode. If you want text of the code below the barcode, you could add it later to the output of this package.". I will thusly close this as a duplicate of a question that explains how to do that.